# Prove or disprove that a graph made by $n$ straight lines is Hamiltonian.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Given $n$ lines, no two of which are parallel and no more than two intersect at the same point. Construct a graph with the intersection of lines as vertices and the line segments as edges. Prove or disprove that this graph is Hamiltonian.

I checked this for many graphs of different sizes and in every case, I could find a Hamiltonian cycle. I know that for n lines, the number of vertices will be n(n-1)/2 and edges n(n-2). I have no clue how to use this information and how to proceed further.

Comment: Welcome to Maths Stack Exchange ! It is very important that you comment your question, what have you done, where are you blocked...

Comment: I checked this for many graphs of different sizes and in every case, I could find a Hamiltonian cycle. I know that for n lines, the number of vertices will be n(n-1)/2 and edges n(n-2). I have no clue how to use this information and how to proceed further.

Comment: See this thesis (https://depositonce.tu-berlin.de/bitstream/11303/5993/4/hoffmann_udo.pdf) and the theorem of Tutte (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path)

Comment: *Hint*: Proceed by induction in $n$. The base case, $n=3$, is obvious. In the inductive step, one must consider how the $n+1$th line can be placed.

Comment: I would add (if this is the intended setting) that this collection of lines/line segments lies in a common plane.  This is suggested by the requirement of "no parallel lines" but it would be best to make this an explicit part of the setup.